# kate: flickery line-number popup

Tags: kate

Kate is showing line numbers in a popup box, like a tool-tip, when I scroll up  or down.

The box flickers when scrolling with touchpad / pointing stick, and I hate it.  Can I disable it?

Version: kate-17.12.1-1.fc27.x86_64

[image: A popup box in the corner of the kate window, showing line numbers]